# Plotly JS Python Trace Name Labels are being cut off

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

How do i make sure that my Trace name label's aren't being cut off?[image]

Comment: Hello Valerio, in order to make answering your next questions easier to answer, please post a minimal code example that can be run to reproduce your chart ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `namelength` in the `hoverlabel` in this way:

```
plot_data = [go.Scatter(x = [1.,2,3], y = [10., 20, 30], name = 'Loremipsumdolorsitamet1',
                        hoverlabel = dict(namelength = 50))]
plot_data += [go.Scatter(x = [1.,2,3], y = [15., 25, 40], name = 'Loremipsumdolorsitamet2')]
pltly.iplot(plot_data)
```

More info here: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-hoverlabel

The code above will give the following chart:
[image]